# How can I prevent Dynamic Pricing overwriting the price of Gravity Form?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I have installed Gravity Forms + Woocommerce Gravity Forms Product Addons + Woocommerce Dynamic Princing (official plugins).

My problem is that Dynamic Pricing overrides the final price but without using addons. Is there a way that the Dynamic Discount fixed price is only used to calculate the base price and then add the addons that the buyer chooses?

No matter what the customer chooses, Dynamic Pricing always overwrites the price in the cart.

Thanks
(I'm sorry if there is an error in my English)

Comment: Depending on your needs, [GP Conditional Pricing](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-conditional-pricing/) might be a better fit for creating dynamic pricing with Gravity Forms and the WooCommerce Gravity Forms Product Addons plugin.

Comment: Thanks @David, I had already reviewed that plugin but I have more than 4,000 products and it is easier for the team to create/edit a table with Dynamic Pricing instead of create 4,000 almost identical forms where only that function changes. Thanks again.